# Need AIDL tutorials

Tags: java, android, aidl

I am working on AIDL and consider the APIDemo for it. But if some one has more knowledge please share it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The tutorial on the android developer site is good.  There are also a bunch of other good ones:

1. http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/48.html
2. http://owenhuangtw.pixnet.net/blog/post/23760257-android-aidl-(android-interface-definition-language)
3. http://www.app-solut.com/blog/2011/04/using-the-android-interface-definition-language-aidl-to-make-a-remote-procedure-call-rpc-in-android/

Comment: I use the following link and it is very helpful for me. http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/48.html

Comment: That one was very helpful to me as well when I had to implement AIDL.  I hope you'll accept my answer.

Comment: First link is dead..please update it

Comment: The 1st link is dead. I found another good one: http://techblogon.com/android-aidl-example-with-code-description-ipc/

Comment: @JaySouper link is dead

Answer (score 6):

Another good AIDL tutorial:

http://mindtherobot.com/blog/37/android-architecture-tutorial-developing-an-app-with-a-background-service-using-ipc/

Answer (score 1):

here is a very good [doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html) over AIDL.

Comment: Correction was a good doc now its just a broken link.

Comment: i just corrected it, not sure who is the peer reviewer...here it goes:

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html

Answer (score 0):

one of the good tutorial for Android AIDL is here. Actually AIDL provide the Binding Different processes running in their own memory location. eg. Binding with Remote Service

http://www.zestofandroid.blogspot.com/

Comment: Instead of linking to your blog, put some content here so that people can use your answer, reference your blog post is fine, but giving a generic link to your blog is not helpful, esp if in the future you have 50+...