# How to handle TCP data?

Tags: android

I am doing a project which continuously receives data from TCP socket.
I need to pass that data to another activity so that I can perform my action.
For passing data every time intent passing is useless.
We can use timer but their could be some data loss.
I need some process like, it should through data continuously in the moment it receives.
please suggest me which is the best process to handle TCP data in this case.
I feel more thank full if you give me an example.

Here is my TCP connection and receiving code

```
Sockets = new Socket("My IP",Port);
while (s.isConnected()) {
in = new BufferedReader(
new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
int nRead;
char[] data = new char[1024 + 1024];        
String decoded = "";                    
while ((nRead = in.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
decoded = new String(data, 0, nRead); **// This decoded data need to pass to another activity.**
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`Handler`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) targeted to [`Looper.getMainLooper()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html#getMainLooper%28%29) to efficiently, repeatedly post data to the UI thread from a background thread.

The [Communicating with the UI Thread](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html) section of the Android Training pages explains how to use a `Handler`. I also wrote [a blog post](http://blog.xebia.com/2013/02/24/android-looper-anatomy/) about Loopers a while ago that reveals a bit about how they work.

Comment: Note that `Handler`s have a limited pool of `Message` objects - only 50 IIRC. The pool is *really* easy to exhaust if you're only using Handlers for cross-thread heavy communication. I'd look into `BlockingQueue` and `BlockingDeque` from java.concurrent.

Comment: @Delyan Interesting. My gut feeling is that if your setup is either pushing messages so quickly or processing them so slowly that this limit becomes a problem, something is wrong in the plan, not in the choice of message queue. Of course, nothing is ever that easy and I'm sure there are exceptions. Assuming pool size is not an issue, which approach would you use?

Comment: `Handler`s and `HandlerThread`s are the way to go if you need *casual* thread communication. However, I just wrote an application parsing an incoming stream of data, passing each line as a message and I can assure you that on my Nexus 4, the message pool was the bottleneck (which is how I found out about it). So, if you're not too spammy go with Handlers (though not on the UI thread if you're doing any processing, use `HandlerThread` instead!). If you're doing serious work, yet want lots and lots of messages, use proper queues, they're closer to the consumer-producer model anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try looking at AIDL? Below are some links

[Need AIDL tutorials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7497970/need-aidl-tutorials)
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html