# onPreviewFrame not being called for every frame that is displayed on SurfaceView

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview

My subclass of `SurfaceView` implements `Camera.PreviewCallback` & `SurfaceHolder.Callback`.

```
private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
private Camera mCamera;

private final FPSCounter fpscounter = new FPSCounter();

public MySurfaceView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    mHolder = getHolder();
    mHolder.addCallback(this);
}

@Override
public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
    fpscounter.logFrame();
    Log.d("fps", String.valueOf(fpscounter.getLastFrameCount()));
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
    synchronized (this) {
        mCamera.stopPreview();

        Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
        parameters.setRecordingHint(true);
        parameters.setPreviewFormat(ImageFormat.NV21);

        mCamera.setParameters(parameters);

        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            mCamera.setPreviewCallback(this);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    synchronized (this) {
        setWillNotDraw(false);
        mCamera = Camera.open();
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    synchronized (this) {
        try {
            if (mCamera != null) {
                mCamera.stopPreview();
                mCamera.release();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("cam error", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

and the `FPSCounter` class

```
private long startTime; 
private int frames, lastFrameCount;

public void logFrame() {
    frames++;
    if (System.nanoTime() - startTime >= 1000000000) {
        lastFrameCount = frames;
        frames = 0;
        startTime = System.nanoTime();
    }
}

public int getLastFrameCount() {
    return lastFrameCount;
}
```

Even though the camera preview is extremely smooth, the `onPreviewFrame()` method is only called about 5 times a second. Why isn't it being called for every frame?

Comment: I'm not sure but I belive is related to buffers and how Android handles it. Here is a link to the sourcecode http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/hardware/Camera.java#Camera.PreviewCallback you may check out the EventHandler class aswell.

Comment: @Raykud After a quick look at the class, I still don't see why it wouldn't call the function everytime.

Answer (score 6):

You probably figured it out already: Camera.setPreviewCallback() puts too much pressure on Garbage Collector. You can use Camera.setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer() instead.

Second, if onPreviewFrame() arrives on the main (UI) thread, then it competes for single CPU time with UI events like touch, layout, or even rendering. To keep onPreviewFrame() on a separate thread, you should open() the camera on a secondary Looper thread, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/19154438/192373.

Third, even in this case, the preview callbacks are serialized. If `fpscounter.logFrame()` and `Log().d` take X milliseconds, then the FPS will not exceed 1000/X.

Answer (score 0):

It is called for every frame. You can refer to online [reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setPreviewCallback%28android.hardware.Camera.PreviewCallback%29) of Camera. Look at this sentence "Installs a callback to be invoked for every preview frame in addition to displaying them on the screen."

Comment: Yes, I've seen that, hence the question. Could you please do a quick run of the code on your device just to check the same.

Comment: Why do you think onPreviewFrame() not called for every frame?

Comment: Because even with a very smooth preview I'm only getting about 4 calls  to onPreviewFrame() per second.