# Capturing Video with 1:1 aspect ratio on Android

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, crop, mediarecorder

I am trying to develop an android app that would record a 15sec 640x640 video using MediaRecorder, extract all frames using ffmpeg, apply some artistic filters using gpuimage and then combine the frames back to a video using ffmpeg.

I'm facing problem in recording a video of resolution 640x640. (Instagram android app does this)

I tried using MediaRecorder's setVideoSize(640, 640) and the output video is 640x640 but the video looks like a 640x480 video stretched vertically to make it 640x640. I guess that's because 640x640 is not a resolution returned by the supported video capture resolution list of the device. Is there any way to tell media recorder to maintain aspect ratio while doing such scaling so that I get a video that was scaled from 640x480 to 640x640 by cropping width wise instead of stretching height wise ?

Comment: My current alternative is to record video at 640x480, extract the frames and crop each frames to 480x480 by dropping 80 pixels from left and right, then upscale each frame to 640x640. But this is a time taking process and if there is anyway I could tell MediaRecorder to maintain aspect ratio when capturing at custom resolution video, the time the users have to wait would be significantly lower.

Comment: My MediaRecorder settings are as follows : `mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA); mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP); mediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(VideoEncoder.H264); mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+‌​"/test.3gp"); mediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(15000); mediaRecorder.setMaxFileSize(50000000); mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(640, 640); mediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30); mediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(3000000); `

Comment: And the ffmpeg command I use to extract frames from the video:


    `String[] ffmpegCommand = {"ffmpeg", "-i", "test.3gp","-r", "30", "-an", "-s", "640x640",  "-qscale:v", "2", "-vsync", "1", "-threads", "4", frame%03d.jpg"};`

Comment: It's strange that crop+scale in ffmpeg is of significance when you also face decoding, artistic filters, and re-encoding. Unless you use HW encoder. You could consider the alternative - receive preview frames (640x480, or maybe 800x600 if your camera supports that), crop and apply filters, and encode - all in real time.

Comment: @AlexCohn Thanks for the comment. I initially tried using the preview frames and 640x480. But Even with just the code to save the frames to sdcard, no matter compressed/uncompressed, the FPS attained is no better than 12 fps even on devices like Nexus4/ GalaxyS4. After googling around a bit I was told that the onPreviewFrame() call back will only be called when the entire platform is comfortable to do so. I couldn't find a single case where onPreviewFrame was called 30 times a second, even if an empty call back is implemented. Life would have been so much better if it could deliver 30FPS.

Comment: here is the way to achieve FPS not worse than MediaRecorder: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19924579/192373

Comment: Thanks for the link @AlexCohn. How ever, I did try both the garbage collection triggering avoidance as well as the threaded camera. Both of these surely improved the performance, but not anywhere near to the performance of the recording that we get when MediaRecorder is used. I always inspect the FPS by extracting all frames from the video (which I record a fast moving target), then manually counting the non-duplicate frames.

Comment: @NikhilMathew Implemented you answer but got `Unable to find a suitable output format for 'transpose=1'
                                                                           transpose=1: Invalid argument`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally ended up with capturing at 640x480, cropping it to 480x480 while splitting to frames using ffmpeg, then finally when frames are combined back to video using ffmpeg, it is up-scaled to 640x640.

```
String[] ffmpegCommand = {"/sdcard/frames/ffmpeg",
    "-i", "/sdcard/frames/test.3gp",
    "-vf", "crop=480:480:80:0,transpose=1",
    "-r", "30", "-an", "-qscale:v", "2", "-vsync", "1", "-threads", "4",  "/sdcard/frames/image%03d.jpg"};
```

The transpose=1 is required when the app is working in portrait mode.

Note : When capturing, to show only the part of the video that will be included in the final cropped video, I added two black bars of 80 pixels on top of the preview display to hide the 80 pixels on either side of the video that later gets cropped of. So the user gets what he sees on the preview.

Comment: can u provide more information / code etc, I am working on same issue

Comment: @MuhammadUmar and Nikhil could you guide me in this issue?