# Camera preview slowing down on re-adding callback buffer in onPreviewFrame()

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview

I'm trying to capture frames from a camera preview so that I can do some image processing on the frames in the background while the user sees the camera preview.

For that, I'm adding 60 buffers initially using `addCallbackBuffer()` in `surfaceChanged()` method of the `SurfaceView` and then on each `onPreviewFrame()` call, I'm re-adding the used buffer.

The problem is re-adding the buffer in `onPreviewFrame()` slows down the preview.

I'm also counting the number of calls to `onPreviewFrame()` every second. In the first second, I'm getting more than 70 calls to `onPreviewFrame()` which decreases to less than 25 in the second second and later.

Here is the code

```
public class MySurfaceView extends SurfaceView implements
            SurfaceHolder.Callback, Camera.PreviewCallback {

private static final int BUFFER_COUNT = 60;

private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
private Camera mCamera;
private boolean isPreviewRunning;

private final FPSCounter fpscounter = new FPSCounter();

private int frameWidth, frameHeight;

private byte[] prevFrameByteArr, currFrameByteArr;

public MySurfaceView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    mHolder = getHolder();
    mHolder.addCallback(this);
}

public byte[] getPrevFrameByteArray() {
    return prevFrameByteArr;
}

public byte[] getCurrFrameByteArray() {
    return currFrameByteArr;
}

public int getFrameRate() {
    return fpscounter.getLastFrameCount();
}

public int getFrameWidth() {
    return frameWidth;
}

public int getFrameHeight() {
    return frameHeight;
}

@Override
public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
    synchronized (this) {
        prevFrameByteArr = currFrameByteArr;
        currFrameByteArr = data;
    }
    mCamera.addCallbackBuffer(data);
    fpscounter.logFrame();
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height) {
    synchronized (this) {
        if (isPreviewRunning)
             mCamera.stopPreview();

        Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
        parameters.setRecordingHint(true);
        parameters.setPreviewFormat(ImageFormat.NV21);

        /* To get better frame rate, get the least resolution that matches the current aspect ratio */
        List<Size> sizes = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
        Size currPreviewSize = parameters.getPreviewSize();
        float ar = (float) (Math.floor(((float) currPreviewSize.width / currPreviewSize.height) * 10) / 10);
        for (Size s : sizes) {
            int w = s.width, h = s.height;
            float resAr = (float) (Math.floor(((float) w / h) * 10) / 10);
            if (ar == resAr) {
                this.frameWidth = w;
                this.frameHeight = h;
                parameters.setPreviewSize(w, h);
                currPreviewSize = s;
                for (int i = 0; i < BUFFER_COUNT; i++) {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[w * h *
                        ImageFormat.getBitsPerPixel(ImageFormat.NV21) / 8];
                    mCamera.addCallbackBuffer(buffer);
                }
                break;
            }
        }

        mCamera.setParameters(parameters);

        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            mCamera.setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer(this);
            mCamera.startPreview();
            isPreviewRunning = true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    synchronized (this) {
        setWillNotDraw(true);
        mCamera = Camera.open();
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    synchronized (this) {
        try {
            if (mCamera != null) {
                mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
                mCamera.stopPreview();
                mCamera.release();
                isPreviewRunning = false;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("cam error", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
}
```

and the `FPSCounter` class

```
private long startTime; 
private int frames, lastFrameCount;

public void logFrame() {
    frames++;
    if (System.nanoTime() - startTime >= 1000000000) {
        lastFrameCount = frames;
        frames = 0;
        startTime = System.nanoTime();
    }
}

public int getLastFrameCount() {
    return lastFrameCount;
}
```

Anybody know how this could be resolved?

Comment: There is a problem with your class: you cannot use the byte array you got from `onPreviewFrame()` after you returned it to Camera buffer pool (`addCallbackBuffer()`). All processing should be done before call to `addCallbackBuffer()`. You can do it in a different method, not in `onPreviewFrame()`; often processing is done in a `native` method, because number crunching in C is still much faster than in Java. You can even push the `data` array in some queue and process it in a separate thread.

Comment: Hi did you received the 30 fps in the below given answer @Alex Cohn actually I work on the same task to get constant fps, but could not able, even if it is related to the device hardware then why it slow down the frame rate from actual device fps rate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not seen Android devices that reliably deliver more than 30 FPS. But one caveat that may cause slowdown is when onPreviewFrame() arrives on the main (UI) thread, and thus competes for time with UI events like touch, layout, or even rendering. Please see how you can painlessly offload the preview callbacks to secondary thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19154438/192373.

At any rate, pre-allocation of 60 buffers smells wrong. If you capture preview frames for more than a second, you must process and recycle the frames in real time. So, 3 buffers should be enough: one is processed by your program, one is free and can be locked by the camera at any moment, and one is locked by the camera and receives the current frame.

Comment: Hi Alex Cohn I tried to Capture the preview frames more than 25 seconds I faced the same Issue but I used setPreviewCallback instead of setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer, It is due to of setPreviewCallback thank you.

Comment: Could you please help me to explain how to reduce time between frames camera api v1... Now I have the best result 600 ms, but I know apps that can do up to 30 pictures per sec... I can't understand how... Thanks in advance