# Strategy for unweight UI thread (Camera.PreviewCallback)

Tags: android, multithreading, performance, android-camera

I'm asking for help. I binded service in an acvitity:

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, X.class);
MainActivity.this.bindService(i, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

This service is designed to decode data from Camera.PreviewCallback (YCbCr_420_SP (NV21)) to RGB. For unweight CPU I limitted framerate and camera resolution. (there isn't live preview).

Problem that I face is overloading UI thread which results slow down showing content on MainActivity (animations, movies). All expensive operations are executing in the service (decoding, reading barcodes).

How can i fix this? I think, that i must create some thread, but how to connect him with Camera.PrviewCallback ?

Thanks and please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have recently explained how an Activity can be modified to take [onPreviewCallback()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.PreviewCallback.html) off the UI thread: [Best use of HandlerThread over other similar classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18149964/best-use-of-handlerthread-over-other-similar-classes#19154438). Same approach can be applied to a service.

Comment: Ok, it works. In this way I had must used Handler to synchronize views placed on onPreviewCallback(), but works great. Thanks again :)