# OnPictureTaken() Timing/Saving Issue

Tags: android, camera

I'm creating a custom camera application (which'll be contained within a larger, main application) that loads up a view with the camera -preview and a picture gallery preview - so the user can either take a picture or select a preexisting one. If the user does take a photo, I just wanna display a confirmation dialog and, if confirmed, pass control back to the main activity. I can't store the photo: need to quickly use it as an attachment, and once sent via the main activity, dispose of it.

The problem comes up when I take a picture and onPictureTaken() is called: it either doesn't work, or takes an absurdly long time for it to save a photo. Also, I can't seem to figure out how to extract the photo right on the spot, without saving it to a directory; I planned on immediately deleting the directory, but there's got to be a cleaner way (essentially, I just wanna access that raw byte array, without having to save it).

I want it to be modular (gonna use the camera a lot in my upcoming projects), and I think that's what's adding to the overall lag.

I followed Google's Developer Android  [Guide on Cameras](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#saving-media), and most of my code is derived from the examples presented there.

I'm also using ActionBarSherlock.

I currently have three classes:

**CameraManager**

```
public class CameraManager {

private static Camera CAMERA;

    /** Check if this device has a camera */
    public static boolean  doesDeviceHaveCamera(Context context) {
        if (context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)){
            return true;
        } 
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static Camera getCameraInstance(){
        CAMERA = null;
        try {
            CAMERA = Camera.open();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
        }
        return CAMERA;
    }
}
```

**CameraPreview**

```
    public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private static final String TAG = "CameraPreview";
    private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    private Camera camera;

    public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {
        super(context);
        this.camera = camera;
        surfaceHolder = getHolder();
        surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS); // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        try {
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            camera.startPreview();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        camera.stopPreview();
        camera.release();
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
        // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.

        if (surfaceHolder.getSurface() == null){
            return;
        }
        try {
            camera.stopPreview();
        } 
        catch (Exception e){
            // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
        }

        // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or
        // reformatting changes here
        camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        // start preview with new settings
        try {
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
            camera.startPreview();
        } 
        catch (Exception e){
            Log.d(TAG, "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

**CameraActivity**

```
public class CameraActivity extends SherlockActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "CameraActivity";
    public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
    public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO = 2;
    private Camera camera;
    private CameraPreview preview;
    private PictureCallback picture = new PictureCallback() { 
        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
            if (pictureFile == null){
                Log.d(TAG, "Error creating media file, check storage permissions: media file is null.");
                return;
            }
            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
                fos.write(data);
                fos.close();
            } 
            catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
            } 
            catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        setContentView(R.layout.camera_view);

        /**Get a camera instance**/
        if(CameraManager.doesDeviceHaveCamera(this)){
            camera = CameraManager.getCameraInstance();
        }
        else{
            return;
        }

        /**Create a SurfaceView preview (holds the camera feed) and set it to the corresponding XML layout**/
        preview = new CameraPreview(this, camera);
        FrameLayout previewContainer = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
        previewContainer.addView(preview);

        /**Set up a capture button, which takes the picture**/
        Button captureButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_capture);
        captureButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                camera.takePicture(null, null, picture);
            }
        });
    }

    /** Create a File for saving an image or video */
    private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type){
        // To be safe, you should check that the SDCard is mounted
        // using Environment.getExternalStorageState() before doing this.

        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "MyDirectory");
        // This location works best if you want the created images to be shared
        // between applications and persist after your app has been uninstalled.

        // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
        if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
            if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
                Log.d("MyDirectory", "failed to create directory");
                return null;
            }
        }
        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.US).format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE){
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
                    "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");
        } 
        else if(type == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
                    "VID_"+ timeStamp + ".mp4");
        } 
        else {
            return null;
        }
        return mediaFile;
    }
}
```

I'm calling *CameraActivity* from a button on my main activity screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem comes up when I take a picture and onPictureTaken() is called: it either doesn't work, or takes an absurdly long time for it to save a photo

It is a large file, one that you are writing to on the main application thread.

> essentially, I just wanna access that raw byte array, without having to save it

Then don't save it. *Carefully* use a static data member to put the byte array somewhere that the main activity can use (and, when you are done with it, `null` out the static reference, so the memory can be garbage-collected).

Comment: So I should start CameraActivity on an AsyncTask within the main activity (the one that calls CameraActivity)?

Comment: @yoaquim: I have no idea what "call CameraActivity" means. If you mean `startActivity()`, there is no point in calling `startActivity()` on a background thread.

Comment: Edited, thanks (I did mean start CameraActivity). Then, within CameraActivity, I should write the file in a separate thread?

Comment: @yoaquim: That would certainly stop your UI from freezing while the writing to disk is going on. Disk and network I/O, in general, should always be done on a background thread.

Answer (score 1):

If you [open the camera on a secondary event thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18149964/best-use-of-handlerthread-over-other-similar-classes/19154438#19154438), your `pictureTaken()` callback will be called on that thread, not hindering UI responsiveness. Note that you can still call `camera.takePicture()` from `onClick()`, i.e. from the UI thread.

This still is not a silver bullet: you may want to offload writing file to a yet another working thread, to let the camera take the next photo. And as [Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware) wrote above, don't write to file if you only need live access to the raw byte array.

Comment: Yeah, it was a silly mistake on  my end. I had actually thought about saving the byte array in a static field like Mark said, but I had second thoughts since they require a lot of caution. Alas, that's what  I did and it worked perfectly. Thanks!