# How can I resume my camera app in Android?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, camera

I have put together a small camera app but have got a problem.

When I resume my app and call `onResume()` I have to reinitialize everything (that is, reopen the camera and create a surfaceview that serves as a camera preview).

Now, my `onResume()` looks like this:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    openCamera();
    startCameraPreview();
}
```

The problem is that the methods in `onResume()`, namely `openCamera()` and `startCameraPreview()`, take a lot of time to finish. And therefore my app takes a lot longer to open up which is not a very nice user experience.

The question is: How can I fix this problem? I already tried using `AsyncTask` but there I ran into the issue of trying to update the UI from a thread other than the main thread.

Any ideas?

Comment: **Why** are those methods slow?  Are you aware that it is perfectly possible for another thread to update the main thread?  `Interface`, `Handler`, `Receiver` etc.

Comment: If you use AsyncTask. the onPostExecute method allows you to update the Main thread. see this :  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: Yes, it is preferable to open camera on a background thread. But still the camera callbacks could interfere with UI. To make sure these callbacks don't make your app unresponsive, you can follow a simple tutorial [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19154438/192373).

Comment: From the code you published, it is not clear where UI updates are involved in `onResume()`.