# How to limit preview fps range in android for camera?

Tags: android, android-camera, frame-rate

Is it possible to limit fps range in android camera..
tried to change the values in .setPreviewFpsRange()... but frame rate are not changed.. it comes continuously 30 frames per second

Comment: how did you check that it is 30 frame per second? can you share the code sample?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `public List<int[]> getSupportedPreviewFpsRange ()` to check what FPS range supported by your device. Here is mine:

> preview-fps-range-values=(10000,10000),(15000,15000),(15000,30000),(30000,30000);

so if I want to change the fps to 15, I can `setPreviewFpsRange(15000,15000)`.

Comment: this worked.. But if only one fps range is available then how to do... any way to restricting call back to avoid more frame rates

Comment: sure. Based on your strategy, you can do anything in preview callback function to programmatically change the FPS. For example, you can drop frames, or sleep thread for a couple of milliseconds.

Comment: used thred.sleep.. but it blocks other thread.. can u give some example for drop frames to do this..

Comment: How did you sleep your thread? You should use it in onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera), in which you can also deal with all preview frames.

Comment: @yushulx can you please take a look on this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30564273/how-to-get-camera-preview-frame-after-every-500ms

Comment: **Thread.sleep()** in **onPreviewFrame()** is dangerous, but even worse if this callback comes on the UI thread. You must [open the camera on a separate HandlerThread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19154438/192373) so that the camera callbacks use that background thread and not the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

I set the preview frame rate to the lowest rate possible with this code, but you could set it to the highest rate possible by using `l_last` instead of `l_first` in the List index (`mCamera` is a member variable that references the Camera and is set elsewhere in the code).

```
Camera.Parameters l_params = mCamera.getParameters();

List<int[]> frameRates = l_params.getSupportedPreviewFpsRange();
int l_first = 0;
int l_last = frameRates.size() - 1;
int minFps = (frameRates.get(l_first))[Camera.Parameters.PREVIEW_FPS_MIN_INDEX];
int maxFps = (frameRates.get(l_first))[Camera.Parameters.PREVIEW_FPS_MAX_INDEX];
l_params.setPreviewFpsRange(minFps, maxFps);

mCamera.setParameters(l_params);
```

Comment: Camera.Parameters has been deprecated in Android L

Comment: I think it should be l_last instead of l_first in the sixth line: "int maxFps = (frameRates.get(l_last))[Camera.Parameters.PREVIEW_FPS_MAX_INDEX];"