# Taking a picture with Android's Camera (API 19): onPictureTaken is not called

Tags: android, android-camera, google-glass, gdk

I'm being frustrated by something that should very simple: taking a picture using Android's camera API (with no preview). I've been following several answers from stackoverflow, but with no success.

Initially I followed this answer (@sush): [How to take pictures from the camera without preview when my app starts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20684553/how-can-i-enable-my-android-app-to-take-pictures-from-the-camera-without-preview/20741300#20741300)

But the **PictureCallback** was never called. I then followed this answer (@Alex Cohn):

> You correctly found that takePicture() should not be called before startPreview() or immediately after it. ([onPictureTaken never called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24917850/onpicturetaken-never-called/24919597#24919597))

Which led me to try three solutions.

### Solution 1

The first solution places a *callback* in SurfaceHolder:

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity
{
    private Camera mCamera;                         

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        takeSnapShot();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause()
    {
        clearCamera();
        super.onPause();
    }

    private void takeSnapShot()
    {
        if (mCamera == null)
        {
            try { mCamera = Camera.open(); }
            catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

            SurfaceView surface = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.preview);
            surface.getHolder().addCallback(mSurfaceHolderCallback);

            try { mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(surface.getHolder()); }
            catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

            mCamera.startPreview();
        }
    }

    private final SurfaceHolder.Callback mSurfaceHolderCallback = new SurfaceHolder.Callback()
    {
        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder)
        {
            try
            {
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
                mCamera.startPreview();
                mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPictureCallback);
            }
            catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {}

        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {}
    };

    private final Camera.PictureCallback mPictureCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback()
    {
        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera)
        {
            FileOutputStream outStream = null;

            try
            {
                File dir_path =
                    Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);

                File pictureFile = new File(dir_path, "snapshot-test.jpg");

                outStream = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
                outStream.write(data);
                outStream.close();
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
            catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
            finally { clearCamera(); }
        }
    };

    private void clearCamera()
    {
        if (mCamera != null)
        {
            try
            {
                mCamera.stopPreview();
                mCamera.release();
                mCamera = null;
            }
            catch (final Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        }
    }
```

This first solution works if I call **takeSnapShot** just once. Unfortunately, I can't get **mSurfaceHolderCallback** to run *SurfaceCreated* multiple times.

### Solution 2

My second solution was to use *PreviewCallback*. In this solution I've re-used *onPause*:

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity
{
    private Camera mCamera;                         
    private boolean mReadyToTakePicture;             

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        takeSnapShot();
    }

    private void takeSnapShot()
    {
        if (mCamera == null)
        {
            try { mCamera = Camera.open(); }
            catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

            mCamera.setPreviewCallback(mRawPreviewCallback);
            SurfaceView surface = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.preview);

            try { mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(surface.getHolder()); }
            catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

            mCamera.startPreview();
        }
    }

    private final Camera.PreviewCallback mRawPreviewCallback = new Camera.PreviewCallback()
    {
        @Override
        public void onPreviewFrame(byte [] rawData, Camera camera)
        {
            int rawDataLength = 0;

            if (rawData != null) { rawDataLength = rawData.length; }
            if (rawDataLength > 0 && !mReadyToTakePicture)
            {
                mReadyToTakePicture = true;
                mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPictureCallback);
            }
            else { mReadyToTakePicture = false; }
        }
    };

    private final Camera.PictureCallback mPictureCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback()
    {
        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera)
        {
            FileOutputStream outStream = null;
            mReadyToTakePicture = false;

            try
            {
                File dir_path =
                        Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);

                File pictureFile = new File(dir_path, "snapshot-test.jpg");

                outStream = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
                outStream.write(data);
                outStream.close();
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
            catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
            finally { clearCamera(); }
        }
    };

    private void clearCamera()
    {
        if (mCamera != null)
        {
            try
            {
                mReadyToTakePicture = false;
                mCamera.stopPreview();
                mCamera.release();
                mCamera = null;
            }
            catch (final Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        }
    }
}
```

In this solution both **mRawPreviewCallback** and **mPictureCallback** are never called.

### Solution 3

My last example is using an *AsyncTask* that waits for a while before actually taking a picture. Hopefully this would give enough time for the preview to be set. In this solution I've re-used *onPause* and *clearCamera*:

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity
{
    private Camera mCamera;                         

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        takeSnapShot();
    }

    private void takeSnapShot()
    {
        if (mCamera == null)
        {
            try { mCamera = Camera.open(); }
            catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

            SurfaceView surface = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.preview);

            try { mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(surface.getHolder()); }
            catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

            mCamera.startPreview();

            new CameraTask().execute(mCamera);
        }
    }

    private class CameraTask extends AsyncTask<Camera, Void, Void>
    {
        protected String doInBackground(Camera... cameras)
        {
            try { Thread.sleep(1500); } catch (InterruptedException e)
            { e.printStackTrace(); }

            mCamera = cameras[0];
            mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPictureCallback);

            return mPicturePath;
        }

        private final Camera.PictureCallback mPictureCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback()
        {
            @Override
            public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera)
            {
                FileOutputStream outStream = null;

                try
                {
                    File dir_path =
                        Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);

                    File pictureFile = new File(dir_path, "snapshot-test.jpg");
                    mPicturePath = pictureFile.getAbsolutePath();

                    outStream = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
                    outStream.write(data);
                    outStream.close();
                }
                catch (FileNotFoundException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
                catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
                finally { clearCamera(); }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

As with *solution 2*, **onPictureTaken** is never called.

In all examples the layout of my *SurfaceView* is as follows (for no preview):

```
<SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/preview"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"></SurfaceView>
```

At this point I'm running out of ideas. My first example was successful in taking one picture, so if I could at least force the app to run **surfaceCreated** multiple times, it should work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I have faced this issue before on gingerbread devices. 
Do the following:

```
mCamera.takePicture(null, null, new Camera.PictureCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onPictureTaken(final byte[] originalData, Camera camera) {
 // logic here
```

});

instead of:

```
 mCamera.takePicture(null, null,myCallback);
```

private PictureCallback mPicallback = new PictureCallback(){
};