# Android camera onPictureTaken never called

Tags: java, android, android-camera

I know that this is a very common problem on Stackoverflow which has quite a few answers, but none of them worked for me and quite a few other people which you can see in many posts like this one:
[Taking a picture with Android's Camera (API 19): onPictureTaken is not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31996128/taking-a-picture-with-androids-camera-api-19-onpicturetaken-is-not-called)

I browsed through quite a few questions similar to this one but never found a working fix.
I have a camera set up after the code from the android documentation and onPictureTaken() is never called after takePicture() is called. I debugged everything and the application always decides to be finished with it's onClick interaction after takePicture() is called and the callback is never executed. If you don't find a solution or don't want to read my nasty code, I would appreciate if you could post a working example from anywhere.
I'm sorry if there are any typos, here's my shortened code:

```
public final class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, PictureCallback {


    private ImageView imageView;
    private SurfaceView surfaceView;
    private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    private Camera mCamera;
    private Parameters parameters;

    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Picture taken");
    }



    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        //some preparation stuff here e.g. Permissions

        mCamera = getCameraInstance();

        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);
        surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
        surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

        Button button = findViewById(R.id.button_id);
        button.setOnClickListener(it - > {
                if (mCamera != null) {
                    mCamera.takePicture(null, null, this);
                }
        }
    }

    private Camera getCameraInstance() {
        Camera cam = null;
        try {
            cam = Camera.open();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "getCameraInstance() - Camera is not available");
            return null;
        }

        return cam;
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            mCamera.startPreview();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
        Log.d(TAG, "surfaceChanged()");
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        mCamera.release();
        mCamera = null;
    }
}
```

I tried:
-letting the activity sleep to let the surface load properly
-tracking onPause() and onResume(), none of them were called
-inlining the pictureCallback
-posting takePicture() to the surfaceView