# android java camera capture from asynctask

Tags: java, android, sockets, camera, udp

I am trying to do a code in an asynctask that takes a picture from the camera and send it to a server over UDP 100 times. However, the PictureCallback isn't called. Can someone please help me?

this is what i tried:

```
public class MainAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {

protected static final String TAG = null;
public MainActivity mainAct;

public MainAsyncTask(MainActivity mainActivity)
{
    super();
    this.mainAct = mainActivity;
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    DatagramSocket clientSocket = null;
    InetAddress IPAddress = null;
    try {
        clientSocket = new DatagramSocket();
        IPAddress = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.15");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    byte [] data;
    DatagramPacket sendPacket;

    try {
        for (int i=0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            publishProgress("");
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ File.separator +"img.jpg");
            while (!file.exists() || file.length() == 0);
            Bitmap screen = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ File.separator +"img.jpg");
            ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            screen.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 15, bytes);
            data = bytes.toByteArray();
            sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length, IPAddress, 3107);
            clientSocket.send(sendPacket);
            file.delete();
        }

        clientSocket.close();


    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        publishProgress(e.getMessage());
    }
    return null;
}

public static void takeSnapShots(MainActivity mainAct)
{
    PictureCallback jpegCallback = new PictureCallback() {
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) 
        {
            FileOutputStream outStream = null;
            try {
                outStream = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"img"+".jpg");    
                outStream.write(data);
                outStream.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally 
            {
                camera.stopPreview();
                camera.release();
                camera = null;
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - jpeg");
        }
        };
    SurfaceView surface = new SurfaceView(mainAct.getApplicationContext());
    Camera camera = Camera.open();
    try {
        camera.setPreviewDisplay(surface.getHolder());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    camera.startPreview();
    camera.takePicture(null,null,jpegCallback);
}


protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
    takeSnapShots(mainAct);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
{
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that `AsyncTask` is the most convenient tool to do the job.

You need a `SurfaceView` that is not simply created out of nowhere, but connected to the screen. You should initialize your **camera** only once, and you cannot call `camera.takePicture()` in a loop. You can call `takePicture()` from `onPictureTaken()` callback, but you should also remember that you cannot work with sockets from the UI thread. Luckily, you can follow the Google recommendations.

> [the recommended way to access the camera is to open Camera on a separate thread](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/cameradirect.html).

and

> [Callbacks will be invoked on the event thread `open(int)` was called from](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html).

If you open camera in a new HandlerThread, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19154438/192373), the picture callbacks will arrive on that beckground thread, which may be used also for networking.

Also, I recommend you to send directly the JPEG buffer that you receive from the camera. I believe that overhead of saving image to file, reading the file to bitmap, and compressing the latter to another JPEG may be way too much. To control the image size, [choose appropriate picture size](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setPictureSize(int,%20int)). Note that the size should be selected from the [list of sizes supported by the specific camera](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getSupportedPictureSizes()).

```
public class CameraView extends SurfaceView 
    implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, Camera.PictureCallback {

    private static final String TAG = "CameraView";

    private Camera camera;
    private HandlerThread cameraThread;
    private Handler handler;
    private boolean bCameraInitialized = false;
    private int picturesToTake = 0;

    public CameraView(Context context, AttributeSet attr) {
        super(context, attr);

        // install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
        // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
        getHolder().addCallback(this);
    }

    @Override public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        cameraThread = new HandlerThread("CameraHandlerThread");
        cameraThread.start();
        handler = new Handler(cameraThread.getLooper());
        hanlder.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {
                openRearCamera();
                bCameraInitialized = false;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        if (camera != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Camera release");
            camera.release();
            camera = null;
            bCameraInitialized = false;
        }
    }

    // finalize the camera init now that we know preview size
    @Override public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, final int w, final int h) {
        Log.w(TAG, "surfaceChanged(" + w + ", " + h + ")");
        if (!bCameraInitialized) {
            cameraSetup(w, h);
            bCameraInitialized = true;
        }
    }

    private void openRearCamera() {
        if (camera != null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "openRearCamera(): camera is not null");
            return;
        }
        try {
            camera = Camera.open(0);
            Log.d(TAG, "Camera ready " + String.valueOf(camera));
        }
        catch (Throwable e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "openRearCamera(): Camera.open() failed", e);
        }
    }

    private void cameraSetup(int w, int h) {

        if (camera == null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "cameraSetup(): camera is null");
            return;
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "Camera setup");
        try {
            Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();

            // still picture settings - be close to preview size
            Camera.Size pictureSize = params.getSupportedPictureSizes()[0];
            params.setPictureSize(pictureSize.width, optimalPictureSize.height);

            camera.setParameters(params);
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(getHolder());
            camera.startPreview();
        }
        catch (Throwable e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to finalize camera setup", e);
        }
    }

    private void sendJpeg(byte[] data) {
        DatagramSocket clientSocket = null;
        InetAddress IPAddress = null;
        try {
            clientSocket = new DatagramSocket();
            IPAddress = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.15");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "failed to initialize client socket", e);
        }
        DatagramPacket sendPacket;
        sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length, IPAddress, 3107);
        clientSocket.send(sendPacket);
        Log.d(TAG, "sent image");
    }

    @Override public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        sendJpeg(data);
        camera.startPreview();
        takePictures(picturesToTake-1);
    }

    public void takePictures(int n) {
        if (n > 0) {
            picturesToTake = n;
            Log.d(TAG, "take " + n + " images");
            camera.takePicture(null, null, this);
        }
        else {
            Log.d(TAG, "all images captured");
        }
    }
}
```

The class above is a compilation from several projects, with error checking reduced to minimum for brevity. It may require some fixes to compile. You simply add a `<CameraView />` to your activity layout, and call its `takePictures` when the user clicks a button or something.

Answer (score 0):

Do you call to your AsyncTask like this? Just to create the AsyncTask is not enouge.

```
new MainAsyncTask(ActivityContext).execute();
```

Comment: Yes, so what do I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this

```
camera.setPreviewDisplay(surface.getHolder());
```

From the docs:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setPreviewDisplay(android.view.SurfaceHolder)

"The SurfaceHolder must already contain a surface when this method is called. If you are using SurfaceView, you will need to register a SurfaceHolder.Callback with addCallback(SurfaceHolder.Callback) and wait for surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder) before calling setPreviewDisplay() or starting preview."

You'd have to do something like this:

```
SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder = surface.getHolder();
surfaceHolder.addCallback(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {}
        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            try {
                camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
                camera.startPreview();
                camera.takePicture(null,null,jpegCallback);
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {}
    }
);
```