# Background OpenGL ES thread with camera preview on Android

Tags: android, multithreading, opengl-es, camera

Is there a way to have a background thread access the camera preview using an OpenGL ES texture?

It is perfectly fine to access the camera preview using OpenGL ES within a view that is visible to the user. I need to access the camera frame within a background thread in an OpenGL context. Download the resulting data using glReadPixels after transformed by a shader and do further processing in the CPU. The user view should not be affected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The supported way to process frame after frame in the background is by using the `onPreviewFrame()` callback. Whatever you do there will not effect the user preview, be it surface or texture.

If you want the `onPreviewFrame()` callbacks to arrive on a background thread, you should `openCamera()` on this thread, and it must be a Handler thread (i.e. to have its Looper), see *[Best use of HandlerThread over other similar classes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19154438/192373)*