# Understanding and speeding up addCallbackBuffer

Tags: java, android, android-camera

I want to understand how the preview buffer passed to `addCallbackBuffer` relates to the `byte[]` array passed through `onPreviewFrame`, which prompts the following related questions.

Q1. I am guessing that the buffer passed in `addCallbackBuffer` is used to store a new camera frame and that before `onPreviewFrame` is called, that buffer is copied into the data buffer passed through `onPreviewFrame`.   If it is the case, that would mean that I can reuse my preview frame buffer by calling `addCallbackBuffer` as soon as I enter `onPreviewFrame` and note at the end of the function when I am done processing the buffer returned by `onPreviewFrame`.  Is that correct?

Q2. I am also not clear about the mechanism for using two preview frame buffers. Say I have two private `byte[]` preview buffers added as follows during initialization:

```
addCallbackBuffer(mPreviewBuffer1);
addCallbackBuffer(mPreviewBuffer2);
```

How do I know which preview buffer was used when I am in `onPreviewFrame` so that I can re-add the correct preview frame buffer with `addCallbackBuffer` again?

```
private byte[] mPreviewBuffer1;
private byte[] mPreviewBuffer1;
...
public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] camera, Camera c) {
  ...
  // how do I decide which buffer to re-add?
  //c.addCallbackBuffer(mPreviewBuffer1);
  //c.addCallbackBuffer(mPreviewBuffer2);
  ...
}
```

Q3. Am I understanding correctly that another thread is responsible for acquiring the frame buffer, i.e. that as long as a preview buffer is in the queue, we will be capturing a frame while `onPreviewFrame` is executing?  If that's not the case, having two call back buffers would not help with speed, would it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Q1** yes, you can return the buffer to camera early if you don't care about its contents. You may not be able to read from this buffer after you call `addCallbackBuffer()` for it, or maybe you can read, but the pixel data will be wrong.

---

**Q2** you can simply return to camera the buffer that you receive on the callback, i.e.

```
@Override public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
  …
  camera.addCallbackBuffer(data);
}
```

In this case you don't care if `data == mPreviewBuffer1` or `data == mPreviewBuffer2`. But the following code is also OK:

```
private byte[][] mPrevieBuffers = new byte[4][];
@Override public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
  for (int i=0; i<mPreviewBuffers.length; i++) {
    if (data == mPreviewBuffers[i]) {
       processData(i);
    }
  }
}
```

---

**Q3** correct, `onPreviewFrame()` executes in parallel with filling the other buffer, but all `onPreviewFrame()` callbacks are called on the same thread. If you want to process as many preview frames as possible, you should **a)** delegate processing to a worker thread (especially, on a multi-core device). Note that you can call safely `addCallbackBuffer()` from that other thread; **b)** [start the camera on a separate Looper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19154438/192373) to have `onPreviewFrame()` decoupled from the UI thread.

Comment: Awesome. You clarified everything. In particular, realizing that there isn't any copy occurring and that the data pointer we get from onPreviewFrame is precisely one of the preview buffers added with the addCallbackBuffer was key!

Comment: There is a memcpy, but it is hidden from us: this is when a frame arrives from the camera HAL (system process) through Binder interface to your (user) process. The frame that is copied to buffer(s) we supply in `addCallbackBuffer()` is also used to display live preview.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int ww, int hh)
{
    if (mCamera == null) return;
    mCamera.stopPreview();
    mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
    //get camera parameters
    prepareSizeScreen();

    mCamera.setParameters(mMyCameraParameters.makeParameters(mCamera.getParameters(), mSizeScreen));
    try
    {
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
    }
    Camera.Size setSize = mCamera.getParameters().getPreviewSize();
    int bufferSize = setSize.width * setSize.height
            * ImageFormat.getBitsPerPixel(mCamera.getParameters().getPreviewFormat()) / 8;

    setupCallback(bufferSize);//this is what you are looking for


    mCamera.startPreview();
}
```

You can choose the amount of callbacks more callbacks more often you will get onPreviewFrame.

```
static final private int NUM_BUFFERS = 5;
private void setupCallback(int bufferSize)
{
    mCamera.setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer(this);
    for (int i = 0; i <= NUM_BUFFERS; ++i)
    {
        byte[] cameraBuffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        mCamera.addCallbackBuffer(cameraBuffer);
    }
}
```

When you get your call back you should use the very same data that you get to set another callback.

```
@Override
public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera)
{//data has NV21 format        
    processData(data);
    camera.addCallbackBuffer(data);//same data is sent for another callback. So you will be managing NUM_BUFFERS at all times.
}
```

And dont forget onDestroy:
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder)
    {
        if (mCamera != null)
        {
            mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
            mCamera.stopPreview();
            mCamera.release();
        }
        mCamera = null;
    }

Comment: this is too slow if you're using an older device (let's say android 4.4 common devices)...