# GLSurfaceView stops calling onDrawFrame

Tags: android, android-camera, glsurfaceview

I'm using `GLSurfaceView` to display the `Camera` feed because when I use an external camera on the device (plugged via USB) the preview is mirrored, and I could only "unmirror" it with a `GLSurfaceView`. It works quite well, but after some time (can be 2 minutes, or 10) the view does not display any more updates and just freezes. I put logs in the `public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl)` method, and I can see it being called often until it freezes, and then no more calls. These are the only logs I get when it freezes:

```
11-29 11:01:39.761 2431-2506/com.xxx D/MyGLSurfaceView: #onDrawFrame
11-29 11:01:58.154 2431-2446/com.xxx I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 9(288B) AllocSpace objects, 3(3MB) LOS objects, 39% free, 6MB/10MB, paused 6.019ms total 25.478ms
11-29 11:02:05.265 2431-2446/com.xxx I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 6(192B) AllocSpace objects, 5(6MB) LOS objects, 39% free, 7MB/12MB, paused 5.228ms total 49.221ms
11-29 11:02:36.496 2431-2446/com.xxx I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 11(336B) AllocSpace objects, 3(3MB) LOS objects, 39% free, 6MB/10MB, paused 7.752ms total 28.387ms
11-29 11:03:10.488 2431-2446/com.xxx I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 242(12KB) AllocSpace objects, 3(3MB) LOS objects, 39% free, 7MB/12MB, paused 12.263ms total 41.651ms
11-29 11:03:24.016 2431-2446/com.xxx I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 18(720B) AllocSpace objects, 5(6MB) LOS objects, 39% free, 6MB/10MB, paused 7.029ms total 26.553ms
11-29 11:03:58.696 2431-2446/com.xxx I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 18(640B) AllocSpace objects, 3(3MB) LOS objects, 39% free, 6MB/10MB, paused 6.227ms total 27.462ms
11-29 11:04:44.049 2431-2446/com.xxx I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 234(12KB) AllocSpace objects, 3(3MB) LOS objects, 29% free, 8MB/12MB, paused 8.683ms total 17.247ms
```

I took some sample code somewhere to use the `GLSurfaveView` as I have no notion on how it works, the code is this:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.SurfaceTexture;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.opengl.GLES11Ext;
import android.opengl.GLES20;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;

import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

class MyGLSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer, SurfaceTexture.OnFrameAvailableListener, Camera.PreviewCallback {
  private static final String TAG = MyGLSurfaceView.class.getSimpleName();

  private static final String vss = "attribute vec2 vPosition;\n" +
    "attribute vec2 vTexCoord;\n" +
    "varying vec2 texCoord;\n" +
    "void main() {\n" +
    "  texCoord = vTexCoord;\n" +
    "  gl_Position = vec4 ( vPosition.x, vPosition.y, 0.0, 1.0 );\n" +
    "}";

  private static final String fss = "#extension GL_OES_EGL_image_external : require\n" +
    "precision mediump float;\n" +
    "uniform samplerExternalOES sTexture;\n" +
    "varying vec2 texCoord;\n" +
    "void main() {\n" +
    "  gl_FragColor = texture2D(sTexture,texCoord);\n" +
    "}";

  private SurfaceTexture mSurfaceTexture;
  private boolean mUpdateTexture = false;
  private FloatBuffer mVertex;
  private FloatBuffer mTextCoordinates;
  private int[] mTexture;
  private int hProgram;

  private Camera mCamera;
  private Camera.Size cameraSize;

  public MyGLSurfaceView(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
  }

  public MyGLSurfaceView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.init();
  }

  private void init() {
    setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
    setRenderer(this);
    setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);

    float[] vtmp = {-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f};
    this.mVertex = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(8 * 4).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
    this.mVertex.put(vtmp);
    this.mVertex.position(0);

    float[] ttmp = {1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f};
    this.mTextCoordinates = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(8 * 4).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
    this.mTextCoordinates.put(ttmp);
    this.mTextCoordinates.position(0);
  }

  @Override
  public void onResume() {
    Log.d(TAG, "#onResume");
    super.onResume();
  }

  @Override
  public void onPause() {
    Log.d(TAG, "#onPause");
    super.onPause();
    this.releaseCamera();
  }

  @Override
  public void onFrameAvailable(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {
    this.mUpdateTexture = true;
    this.requestRender();
  }

  @Override
  public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
    // process bytes here
  }

  @Override
  public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
    Log.d(TAG, "#onSurfaceCreated");

    this.initTexture();
    this.mSurfaceTexture = new SurfaceTexture(mTexture[0]);
    this.mSurfaceTexture.setOnFrameAvailableListener(this);
    this.mSurfaceTexture.getTransformMatrix(new float[16]);

    try {
      this.openCamera();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      this.releaseCamera();
    }

    GLES20.glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
  }

  @Override
  public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
    Log.d(TAG, "#onSurfaceChanged");

    GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

    this.mCamera.startPreview();
    this.mCamera.setPreviewCallback(this);

    this.hProgram = loadShader();
  }

  @Override
  public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    Log.d(TAG, "#onDrawFrame");

    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    synchronized (this) {
      if (this.mUpdateTexture) {
        this.mSurfaceTexture.updateTexImage();
        this.mUpdateTexture = false;
      }
    }

    GLES20.glUseProgram(this.hProgram);

    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, this.mTexture[0]);

    int th = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(this.hProgram, "sTexture");
    GLES20.glUniform1i(th, 0);

    int ph = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(this.hProgram, "vPosition");
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(ph, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 4 * 2, this.mVertex);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(ph);

    int tch = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(this.hProgram, "vTexCoord");
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(tch, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 4 * 2, this.mTextCoordinates);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(tch);

    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

    GLES20.glFlush();
  }

  private void initTexture() {
    this.mTexture = new int[1];
    GLES20.glGenTextures(1, this.mTexture, 0);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, this.mTexture[0]);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
  }

  private static int loadShader() {
    int vshader = GLES20.glCreateShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    GLES20.glShaderSource(vshader, vss);
    GLES20.glCompileShader(vshader);
    int[] compiled = new int[1];
    GLES20.glGetShaderiv(vshader, GLES20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS, compiled, 0);
    if (compiled[0] == 0) {
      Log.e("Shader", "Could not compile vshader");
      Log.v("Shader", "Could not compile vshader:" + GLES20.glGetShaderInfoLog(vshader));
      GLES20.glDeleteShader(vshader);
      vshader = 0;
    }

    int fshader = GLES20.glCreateShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    GLES20.glShaderSource(fshader, fss);
    GLES20.glCompileShader(fshader);
    GLES20.glGetShaderiv(fshader, GLES20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS, compiled, 0);
    if (compiled[0] == 0) {
      Log.e("Shader", "Could not compile fshader");
      Log.v("Shader", "Could not compile fshader:" + GLES20.glGetShaderInfoLog(fshader));
      GLES20.glDeleteShader(fshader);
      fshader = 0;
    }

    int program = GLES20.glCreateProgram();
    GLES20.glAttachShader(program, vshader);
    GLES20.glAttachShader(program, fshader);
    GLES20.glLinkProgram(program);

    return program;
  }

  private void openCamera() throws IOException {
    this.mCamera = Camera.open();

    final Camera.Parameters parameters = this.mCamera.getParameters();
    parameters.setPreviewSize(1280, 720);
    this.mCamera.setParameters(parameters);

    this.mCamera.setPreviewTexture(this.mSurfaceTexture);
  }

  private void releaseCamera() {
    synchronized (this) {
      try {
        if (this.mCamera != null) {
          this.mCamera.stopPreview();
          this.mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
          this.mCamera.release();
          this.mCamera = null;
        }
      }
      catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: No, it doesn't look like the Garbage Collector uses all your CPU. And there is no reason to suspect OpenGL. It could be that the video gets stuck somewhere up the pipe. USB video is not very reliable on Android, and even some HW pieces may even get too hot and fail. You could try to turn off display and only log the coming frames: does this last longer?

Comment: one little precision: in the `public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera)` if I put a log, it will still be called. So it seems the preview is still working

Comment: OK. Maybe you don't need previewCallback at all. It wastes electrons for no good. Another note is that it's not a good practice to open camera on the UI thread. To keep all camera callbacks off the UI thread, you need an separate looper, see *[Best use of HandlerThread over other similar classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18149964/best-use-of-handlerthread-over-other-similar-classes/19154438#19154438)*

Comment: well, although I do need to use the previewCallback since I am processing the frames, using another thread as you suggested makes things faster and so far haven't seen a single freeze...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it looks like the core problem was that image processing (which is launched from `onPreviewFrame()` callback) caused congestion on the main thread.

Running camera on the main thread is a bad practice, and can cause many weird effects on different devices. The new **camera2** API handles this correctly, but if for any reason you must use the *deprecated* Camera API, please move `Camera.open()` and all callbacks to a [background HandlerThread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18149964/best-use-of-handlerthread-over-other-similar-classes/19154438#19154438).

Another optimization: switch to [setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer(android.hardware.Camera.PreviewCallback)) to reduce camera buffer allocation and garbage collection costs.