# Camera Callback not working on version 8.1

Tags: android, sdk, android-camera

I need help in figuring out why my code is not working on an Android device at version 8.1, this same piece of code works fine on version 8.0 and below.

`minSdkVersion = 19`
`targetSdkVersion = 26`
`compileSdkVersion = 26`

Some context, I'm taking a picture through the camera when there are multiple failed passcode attempts, the app is running in the foreground. The app invokes this method which preps the camera device and provides the PictureCallback for a JPEG format.

In the logs I can see

> takePicture called

But, `onPictureTaken` does not get invoked.

Here is the code:

```
        sLogger.info(TAG + "takePicture called.");
    try {
        mCamera.takePicture(null, null, null, new PictureCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                if (data == null) {
                    sLogger.error(TAG + "Received null data in onPictureTaken from Camera PictureCallBack");
                    return;
                }
                pictureTaken(data, orientation);
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        lookoutCamFailed();
        sLogger.error(TAG + "takePicture failed.", e);

    }
```

Adding Logs:

> 07-20 01:22:20.206  1264  2946 D ActivityManagerPerformance: AMP_release() ACT_START
>
> 07-20 01:22:20.225 27040 29514 I MyApp : [CameraManager.initPreview:742]                    Cam: Preview started.
>
> 07-20 01:22:20.226   599  1485 I QCamera :  getCameraInfo: 392: E camera id (1), mNumOfCameras (2)
>
> 07-20 01:22:20.226   599  1485 I QCamera :  getCamInfo: 8789: camera 1 resource cost is 100
>
> 07-20 01:22:20.226   599  1485 I QCamera :  getCameraInfo: 409: camera id = 1, facing info = FRONT
>
> 07-20 01:22:20.227   599  1485 E QCamera :  checkCameraCondition: 1061: camera id(1), camera facing(1), camera type(1)
>
> 07-20 01:22:20.227   599  1485 I QCamera :  getCameraInfo: 424: X camera id (1)
>
> 07-20 01:22:20.230   855  2354 D CameraClient: sendCommand (pid 27040)
> 07-20 01:22:20.230   855  2354 D CameraClient: ENABLE_SHUTTER_SOUND (0, 0)
> 07-20 01:22:20.230   855  2354 D CameraClient: enableShutterSound (pid 27040)
>
> 07-20 01:22:20.230 27040 29514 I MyApp : [CameraManager.disableShutterSoundIfPossible:531]  MyAppCam: call to enableShutterSound succeeded.
>
> 07-20 01:22:20.231 27040 29514 I MyApp : [CameraManager.prepAndTakePicture:863]             MyAppCam: takePicture called.
>
> 07-20 01:22:20.231   855  2354 D CameraClient: takePicture (pid 27040): 0x100
>
> 07-20 01:22:20.232   855  2354 D CameraClient: enableMsgType : msg(0x100, 0xd0d)
>
> 07-20 01:22:20.232   855  2354 D SecCameraCoreManager: enableMsgType : msg(In:0x100, Out:0xd0d)
>
> 07-20 01:22:20.232   855  2354 I ShotCommon: enableMsgType : msg(In:0x100, Out:0xd0d)
>
> 07-20 01:22:20.232   855  2354 D SecCameraCoreManager: takePicture
> 07-20 01:22:20.234  1264  1447 I EDMNativeHelperService: isCameraEnabled
> 07-20 01:22:20.235  1264  1447 D RestrictionPolicy: isCameraEnabled ret(true) userId(0) cxtInfo.mCallerUid(10034) cxtInfo.mContainerId(0)
>
> 07-20 01:22:20.235   855  2354 E SecCameraCoreManager: checkTemperature (0)
>
> 07-20 01:22:20.235   855  2354 D SecCameraCoreManager: takePicture:stop IT Policy checking thread
>
> 07-20 01:22:20.283   599 29526 I QCamera :  procEvtPreviewReadyState: 924: QCAMERA_SM_EVT_GET_PARAMS ReadyState
>
> 07-20 01:22:20.285   855  2354 D ShotSingle: takePicture : supportedPictureFormat = jpeg,nv21
>
> 07-20 01:22:20.285   855  2354 I ShotSingle: takePicture : backup picture format to jpeg
>
> 07-20 01:22:20.285   855  2354 I ShotSingle: takePicture : normal, jpeg
> 07-20 01:22:20.285   599  1485 I QCamera :  take_picture: 1391: [KPI Perf] take_picture: E PROFILE_TAKE_PICTURE camera id 1
>
> 07-20 01:22:20.286   599  1485 I QCamera :  take_picture: 1409: [KPI Perf] take_picture : X
>
> 07-20 01:22:20.286   599 29604 I QCamera :  take_picture_thread: 1073: [KPI Perf] take_picture_thread : E
>
> 07-20 01:22:20.286   599 29604 I QCamera :  take_picture_internal: 1105: [KPI Perf] take_picture_internal: E camera id 1
>
> 07-20 01:22:20.286   599 29604 I QCamera :  take_picture_internal: 1229: take_picture_internal Flash Mode=0, LLS mode=0, Auto LLS mode=0, NumOfSnaps=1
>
> 07-20 01:22:20.286   599 29526 E QCamera :  procEvtPreviewReadyState: 1099: Error!! cannot handle evt(25) in state(1)
>
> 07-20 01:22:20.286   599 29604 I QCamera :  take_picture_internal: 1361: [KPI Perf] take_picture_internal: X
>
> 07-20 01:22:20.287   599 29604 I QCamera :  take_picture_thread: 1077: [KPI Perf] take_picture_thread : X
>
> 07-20 01:22:20.287 27040 29514 I MyApp : [CameraManager$4.run:779]                          MyAppCam: surfaceDestroyed called.
>
> 07-20 01:22:20.321  2750  2750 D io_stats: !@ 179,0 r 553172 42202994 w 299093 5907016 d 11954 2375296 f 81990 82006 iot 648070 657873 th 51200 0 0 pt 0 inp 0 0 67436.843
>
> 07-20 01:22:20.330  1264  2292 W zygote  : Long monitor contention with owner Binder:1264_1E (12984) at android.content.pm.ParceledListSlice com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.getInstalledPackages(int, int)(PackageManagerService.java:11443) waiters=0 in android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.getApplicationInfoInternal(java.lang.String, int, int, int) for 540ms
>
> 07-20 01:22:20.331  1264  2259 W zygote  : Long monitor contention with owner Binder:1264_1E (12984) at android.content.pm.ParceledListSlice com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.getInstalledPackages(int, int)(PackageManagerService.java:11443) waiters=1 in java.lang.String com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.getInstantAppPackageName(int) for 481ms
>
> 07-20 01:22:20.335  1264  2293 W zygote  : Long monitor contention with owner Binder:1264_D (2292) at int com

Comment: There are no exceptions in the log either, just that code never executes.

Comment: If you can capture full system logcat (not just your app's logcat), and add it to the question, it would be easier to see what's going wrong in the camera device implementation.

Comment: You should open the camera on a background Handler thread (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/19154438/192373). Otherwise, the camera callbacks happen on the Main thread. If **onPictureTaken()** takes too long, this could cause this kind of problem.

Comment: *"I can't use Camera2 yet as my minimum sdk version is 19"* – I understand your reluctance to keep two versions of code where one could be enough, but the good practice these days is to use the new **camera2** API on devices that have *native* support for this API, and also use the *deprecated* Camera API on systems below Lollipop or those with LEGACY camera.

Comment: Thanks @AlexCohn checking it out.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation; it looks like a preview must be started before a picture can be taken. Do you have a surface view that the camera is binding to?

`This method is only valid when preview is active (after startPreview()). Preview will be stopped after the image is taken;`

The above is from the [api docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera#takePicture(android.hardware.Camera.ShutterCallback,%20android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback,%20android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback,%20android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback)).

It's also worth mentioning that the Camera API is deprecated; you'll want to use Camera2 if you're looking at maintaining this app in the future!

Comment: Yes, I'm binding a surface view to the camera. The preview starts fine. And as mentioned this works fine on 8.0 but not on 8.1. I can't use Camera2 yet as my minimum sdk version is 19.