# Torch: How to register a torch callback in another thread?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camera2, flashlight, android-thread

I am trying to register a [CameraManager.TorchCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraManager.TorchCallback) using [CameraManager.registerTorchCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraManager.html#registerTorchCallback(android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager.TorchCallback,%20android.os.Handler)) into a specific thread (ie: different from the UI Thread).

My code is quite basic for an [Camera2](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary) implementation:

1. Get the [CameraManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraManager)
2. Get the camera id [from the manager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraManager.html#getCameraIdList())
3. Register my [CameraManager.TorchCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraManager.TorchCallback) using [CameraManager.registerTorchCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraManager.html#registerTorchCallback(android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager.TorchCallback,%20android.os.Handler))
4. Update the Torch status [using the CameraManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraManager.html#setTorchMode(java.lang.String,%20boolean))

If I run that code in the main thread, everything is working great, when I run it into another thread class (overriding `run`), the callback is never called. I am ensuring that my thread is not terminated, visible on the Android studio profiler. There is something with the registration and the threading I don't understand.

Have you ever tried that kind of implementation?

Any idea is welcome!

Comment: You call `registerTorchCallback()` with **null** handler from not-UI-thread?

Comment: I tried using **null** and also using a new **Handler** created from the thread.

Comment: This sets the callback to UI thread. Try to create a new HandlerThread and get a Handler for it.

Comment: Thank you @AlexCohn it worked using the `HandlerThread`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you call **registerTorchCallback()** from a background thread, the callback will still be posted to UI thread. You must [create a new HandlerThread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19154438/192373) and get a Handler for it.