# Android Share Service with Multiple Apps

Tags: android, android-service

My problem is, that i have multiple apps which are scanning for beacons. I want to develop one service which i can use in all of my apps and inform the apps of scanned beacons. 
I read this thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/6204631/3180977 and a shared service is possible with the android:process attribute. Can anyone explain how to implement a service in two applications and the communication with the service?

Comment: Try AIDL service? take a tutorial here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7497970/need-aidl-tutorials

Comment: Yes.You can try with either aidl or messanger.

Comment: Thank you. Can i use a "normal" service in an AIDL service? Thats a strange combination i know. But i use the Radius Networks Library for Beacons. And there is also a service defined.

Comment: for inter process communication you can use aidl or messenger